# What does the second argument do in the .tickSize(10, 1) in d3.axis?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have been going through some code and I encountered `.tickSize(10,1)` and `.tickSize(10, 0)` I know the first argument fixes the tickSize. Can anybody explain what the second argument do?

Comment: Which version of D3 are you using?

Comment: The version is v7.6.1.

Comment: @SathishKannan did you end up figuring out what the second argument does in the `.tickSize()` method?

Comment: Yes. Your answer is useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sets the size of the first and last ticks on the axis. You can play with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zUj3E/2/) to see what changing the second parameter does but here are some screenshots to demonstrate it:

```
    var axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(scale)
        .orient("right")
        .ticks(10)
        .tickSize(10,1) // <-------------- Set outer tick size to 1
        .tickFormat(formatPercent);
```

**Rendered Axis:**

[image]

Changing the code to `.tickSize(10,50)` results in an axis that looks like the following (notice the size of the first and last 'outer' ticks):

[image]